# Conversão monetária PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

Preciso converter um valor `$1,500,35` (padrão americano), para `R$1.500,35` (padrão brasileiro), porém a linguagem usada no banco é americana e as funções que conheço só convertem o valor para a linguagem atual do banco. Como posso fazer isso?

Exemplo de consulta que estou usando:

```
select (invoice_data->'valor_cobrado')::money as "Valor acumulado" from tb_invoice where invoice_number = 4653801
```

> Resultado da query: $14,825.00
>   Preciso retornar isto: R$ 14.825,00

Comment: Pode ser só porque não está claro, mas parece não fazer sentido. Mostre melhor o que deseja.

Comment: padrão americano, e do banco de dados: `000,000,000.00`. na linguagem, segue o mesmo padrão, só vai mudar na exibição, de acordo com o que você escolher... você deve ao menos falar qual linguagem está usando e mostrar o código que quer implementar

Comment: particularmente, utilizo numeric, e não money... deixo a formatação pro lado da aplicação

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se você pretende fazer a conversão direto no banco de dados, na select, você pode usar o comando `to_char(number, format)`.

No format, utilizar `0` significa que aquela casa é obrigatória. Utilizar `9` significa que é opcional.

O caractere `L` indica que um idioma deve ser utilizado, `G` um grupo (',' em inglês, '.' em pt-br) e `D` indica a casa decimal ('.' em inglês, ',' em pt-br)

Seguindo [essa documentação](http://pgdocptbr.sourceforge.net/pg80/functions-formatting.html), vemos nas notas de rodapé no fim da página que precisa ser realizado algumas alterações de locale no pg:

```
set lc_numeric to 'pt_BR'; 
set lc_monetary to 'pt_BR';
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_TERRITORY="BRAZIL";
```

Para alterar o encoding do PgSQL, eu recomendo a leitura [deste doc](https://littleoak.wordpress.com/2008/09/23/corrigindo-maldito-encoding-do-postgres-para-poder-usar-banco-de-dados-latin1-ou-outro-e-mudar-o-encoding-do-sistema-operacional-ubuntu-ou-debian/).

Segue exemplos:

```
SELECT to_char(213456.789,'L000G000G000D99');
SELECT to_char(213456.789,'L999G999G990D99'); 
SELECT to_char(0.789,'L999G999G990D99'); 
SELECT to_char(.7,'L999G999G990D99');
```

Comment: Ao Testar os exemplos acima: 

ERROR:  multiple decimal points
********** Error **********

ERROR: multiple decimal points
SQL state: 42601

Comment: Atualizei a resposta! Aprofundei um pouco mais o assunto, e corrigo um typo (Eu tinha trocado os 'D' com os 'G' no format).

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente como esperado, já tinha lido esta documentação mas não tinha ficado tao claro quanto sua explicação, muito obrigado.

Comment: Onde coloco as configurações mencionadas? Não entendi onde fica esse locale

Comment: @BrunoFelipe para garantir que o valor seja formatado com duas casas decimais então trocamos o 99 no final por 00. Meu código ficou assim: to_char(valo, '"R$" FM999G999G999G990D00')  eu também adicionei uns 9 a mais para garantir que valores maiores também sejam formatados corretamente

Answer (score 1):

Bem. bonito não é!
Mas Poderia fazer o seguinte:

```
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE('$14,825.00'::text,'$','R$ '),',','|'),'.',','),'|','.')
```

No seu exemplo acredito que deva ficar assim:

```
select REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(((invoice_data->'valor_cobrado')::money)::text,'$','R$ '),',','|'),'.',','),'|','.') as "Valor acumulado" from tb_invoice where invoice_number = 4653801
```

Entendendo o que está sendo feito, nesta alternativa você converteria o campo money para text, e dai faz as alterações de caracteres.

O ideal seria alterar o locale do seu banco postgres, para pt-br, desta maneira problemas como este e/ou o formato de data para o padrão do Brasil seriam solucionados.

Espero ter Ajudado.
Busque sempre o Conhecimento. :)